# How can I do this easier?

Tags: c++, class

Let's say I have two classes, `a` and `b`, and I have 2 objects, `choice1` and `choice2`.

I ask the user to enter a number. If user enters `1`, I will use `choice1`, otherwise `choice2` if it is `2`.

When I try to use the object which the user has chosen, I don't know how I will proceed because I don't know which object it is.

Is there a way I can manage this easier than what I did below?

```
int choice;
a choice1;
b choice2;
cout << "Enter 1 or 2";
cin >> choice;

if(choice == 1)
   choice1.setName("Carl");
else
   choice2.setName("Carl");
```

Comment: Do `a` and `b` have a common base class?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the choice objects later. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @FredLarson Yes they have same base class

Comment: Can what you want to do with the choices be done using the base class interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, you say that `a` and `b` have a common base class.  In which case, `setName()` should be a member of that base class, and then you can do this:

```cpp
base *b;
if (choice == 1)
    b = &choice1;
else
    b = &choice2;

/* alternatively:
base *b = (choice == 1) ? static_cast<base*>(&choice1) : static_cast<base*>(&choice2);
*/

b->setName("Carl");
```

If later on, you add more objects that also share this common base class, then consider using an array rather than a series of `if`s, eg:

```cpp
int choice;
a choice1;
b choice2;
c choice3;
...
base* choices[] = {&choice1, &choice2, &choice3};

cout << "Enter 1-3";
cin >> choice;

if ((choice >= 1) && (choice <= 3))
    choices[choice-1]->setName("Carl");
```